# Photoshop design from px to dp

Tags: android

I've got a final app design made i Photoshop where everything is measured in PX.
Now I realize that Android apps are using DP for font-sizes and other things.

Is there any way I can convert PX to DP ?

Answer (score 13):

On a more practical note, you have a few choices in increasing work and fidelty:

1. Have your resources scaled for 160 dots per inch, put them in your `res/drawable` directory, and let the OS scale them to look right on the device.
2. Make two copies of your resources:  one at 160 dots per inch in your `res/drawable` and one at 240 dots per inch in your `res/drawable-hdpi` directory.  Let the OS scale for the exact device starting from a pretty close number.
3. Decide that you don't want any scaling and have raw pixels, so put your assets in the `res/drawable-nodpi` directory.  This means that at 320x480 (pixel) graphic might be 2 inches by 3 inches on one phone but only 1 1/3 inches by 2 inches on another screen.
4. Specify the exact scaling strategy for your work, using the `draw9patch` tool.  This can be very useful for keeping the corners of boxes from getting the "jaggies" from scaling and for making full screen graphics cope with different aspect ratios.
5. Make separate graphics for every device you care about and fall back on scalable graphics for the rest.  You will need to outrun zealots waving style guides trying to convince you not to do it this way.

Oh, and as a gotcha, specify `sp` for your fonts, instead of `dp` or `pt`.  A 10 point font would be a 22 sp font [ =10 * (160/72) or = number of points times 2.222].  `sp` units scale with user preferences for small, medium, or large fonts.

Answer (score 5):

From [this list](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html#Dimension) of the dimension units supported by Android, here's a description of DP:

> Density-independent Pixels - an abstract unit that is based on the physical density of the screen. These units are relative to a 160 dpi screen, so one dp is one pixel on a 160 dpi screen. The ratio of dp-to-pixel will change with the screen density, but not necessarily in direct proportion. Note: The compiler accepts both "dip" and "dp", though "dp" is more consistent with "sp".

This means that the "conversion" between pixels and DP will not be consistent -- on some devices, the ratio might be 1DP = 160px, but it could theoretically be anything. This is all well and good when you're setting the width of a button to, say, `100dp` (since it will get rendered dynamically), but it presents a problem when you have images which must have a fixed size.

Read this page on "[Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)" -- Android has something called [resource directory qualifiers](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers), which let you create size- and density-specific versions of your image resources. For example, for low-density screens, you could create a smaller version of your image and place it in the `drawable-ldpi` directory (or `drawable-hdpi` for high-density screens).

---

**tl;dr** You can't practically "convert from PX to DP" (since the ratio is not fixed), but you can create multiple versions of your images and tell Android which to use with resource directory qualifiers.

Comment: Then how do I calculate font-sizes ?
I know that in my layout (PSD) they're 25px.  But I need to recalculate this size for the developers.

Text should not be as images, since this app is multilingual.

Comment: @Dammark For font-sizes, you should use `sp` (scale-independent pixels). This is basically the same thing as `dp`, but scaled by the user's font size preference (see the above list of dimension units for more info).

Answer (score 0):

A pixel is PX and the DP or DIP are device independent pixels. I don't think that you need to convert these. But you can use scalable 9patch images using the `draw9patch` tool from the android tools.

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue but now got the Solution.

Why you not use the online convertor to see which dp or px you have to for different resolution of android device ??

See this link: [this link](http://labs.skinkers.com/content/android_dp_px_calculator/) which helps me a lot and also helps you.

Enjoy coding.

Answer (score 0):

This is a online DP/PX Converter tools: http://labs.rampinteractive.co.uk/android_dp_px_calculator/